# How many loops until ++$i beats $i++

Tags: php, loops

Using PHP, does it make a difference to use `++$i` instead of `$i++` in a for-loop? I once read somewhere that `++$i` is faster, as the previous value does not have to be stored, as `$i++` returns the value prior the increment, so the value must be stored before incrementing it.

How many loops would I need to feel some significant speed improvement? Like this example:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10000000000; ++$i)
```

instead of:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10000000000; $i++)
```

I always was just curious about this, so I am looking forward to your answers.

Comment: `++$i` will run 1 time lesser then of the `$i++`

Comment: Did you try testing it yourself?

Comment: Have you benchmarked it yourself?  It's heavily dependant on PHP version, server architecture, server load and a whole host of other variables.  Either way it's a [tag:micro-optimization]

Comment: @zz that's utter nonsense, they will loop the same number of times.

Comment: Also, the interpreter can possibly optimize the code when the return value of the `++$i` expression is not used.

Comment: Dont micro optimize, Theres very little differnce, So little that its highly unlikely ever to be the most unoptimized part of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to make some tests, but difference is so random(depends on your computer load) and low, so it can be ignored. You can try to run this test by your own if you want to.

```
<?php
  $start=microtime(true); // start timer

  for($i = 0; $i < 10000000000; ++$i) {

  }

  $end=microtime(true); // end timer
  echo $totaltime=$end-$start; // echo results
?>
```

In my opinion, such micro-optimizations is a wasting of time and likely it can cause some hard-to-find mistakes in your code, so be careful with it.

Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- Donald Knuth

Answer (score 4):

Let me answer you by quoting a passage from the Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy:

> **Q:** Have you any idea how much damage that bulldozer would suffer if I just let it roll straight over you?
>
> **A:** None at all!

Pragmatically speaking there's no performance difference between using `$i++` or `++$i` inside a `for` loop; performance will not suffer if you use the "wrong" one.

If you want to write `++$i` because you feel that it looks nicer or better conveys the meaning you wish it to have, then by all means do it; but there's no relevant objective argument to be made for either way of writing.

Answer (score 0):

++$i increases the number before use and $i++ will increase after use.

You almost always expect $i to increase after you use it. I have never needed to use ++$i.
It should be faster as it counts 1 less than $i++, but you really should not think about stuff like that or that a loop is faster going backwards and so forth. If that is the case, it will be "fixed" shortly and after all your work you end up with unreadable and very weird code, that is easy to break.